# How to track and save head-gaze cursor position a file for Hololens 1

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am using `Microsoft Hololens 1` developer's edition for my research in `augmented reality`. I want to track head `gaze cursor` or `head gaze position` information through the application.

Please guide how many possible ways to track `head gaze` or `head-gaze cursor` raw data information for my research.

Is there any possibility to develop the application to record head-gaze information of coordinates with timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

`Cursor.transform.position` gives you the position of the cursor.

`Camera.main.transform.position` gives you the position of the camera.

`Camera.main.transform.forward` gives you the direction of the gaze.

I suggest you make [your own gaze cursor](http://www.appzinside.com/2016/11/10/create-your-own-gaze-which-interacts-with-holographic-objects-for-hololens/) so you fully understand how it works and how to get information out of it.

Answer (score 0):

> Please guide how many possible ways to track head gaze or head-gaze cursor raw data information for my research.

What kind of data do you mean by “raw data”?If you mean the raw data from the sensor at the hardware level, the answer is no.

But if your expectation is to get the direction and origin of Gaze and the position of  Head-Gaze Cursor. You can get that from [`GazeProvider`](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/Gaze.html#gazeprovider) at MRTK:

```
void LogGazeDirectionOrigin()
{
    Debug.Log("Position at which the gaze hit an object: "
        + CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.HitInfo.point);
    Debug.Log("Gaze is looking in direction: "
        + CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.GazeDirection);
Debug.Log("Gaze origin is: "
        + CoreServices.InputSystem.GazeProvider.GazeOrigin);
}
```

The [`GazeProvider`](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/Gaze.html#gazeprovider) as an Input Source so users can interact with objects through the use of a pointer. The above code shows how to obtain hit information and call the field [`point`](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityRaycastHit.html#Microsoft_MixedReality_Toolkit_Input_MixedRealityRaycastHit_point) in it to obtain the cursor position.
In addition, MRTK does not provide a method that returns the position of the cursor with a timestamp. If you can tolerate a slight delay there's nothing preventing you from doing it in your own code.